# Need help on eclipse project config - Could not find class when debugging on device (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm new to Android and today I've found an Android library on Github. Link: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

I've cloned the project to my computer and imported 3 projects to Eclipse: 2 from the cloned directory and 1 from sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat.

Here is my "MainActivity" project properties:

- Android >> library: android-support-v7-appcompat, Library-ListViewAnimations
- Java Build Path >> projects: android-support-v7-appcompat

There're no error remarks in package explorer, however, when i run the project, some errors happen like this:

12-01 01:05:22.189: E/dalvikvm(2924): Could not find class 'com.haarman.listviewanimations.appearanceexamples.AppearanceExamplesActivity', referenced from method com.haarman.listviewanimations.MainActivity.onAppearanceClicked

The entire log file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct2fhgy0m0lvdgn/log.txt

Thanks for any help!

**Update: I've found the solution:**

The problem comes from a jar mismatch

```
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] Versions found are:
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] Path: /Code/Android/Git/Others/ListViewAnimations/example/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity]    Length: 556198
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity]    SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] Path: /Code/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity]    Length: 621451
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity]    SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2013-12-01 09:34:06 - MainActivity] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Delete android-support-v4.jar in my libs folder and everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have referenced the library properly in your project. Right click your project and select Android from the left panel and add a reference to the library in the library section.

```
    ![Adding a reference to a library project][1]
```

Comment: I've already referenced the project:

Here is my "MainActivity" project properties:

Android >> library: android-support-v7-appcompat, Library-ListViewAnimations

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on their github page under **Setup**.  You can just download the jar files and stick tehm in the libs folder.  Download the entire project to see what other jars they have in their libs folders.  It looks like their project is dependent on one or more others (like the NineOldAndroids.jar).

Comment: I dont understand what they mean by "Add the .jar files to your project's libs folder, or add them as external jars to your project's build path." Which project should I add them to? Create a new one? By the way, 'NineOldAndroids.jar' is already included in 'Library-ListViewAnimations' project.

Comment: I got the idea, however when I download the jar files, add them to libs folder and run, the same behaviour happened :(